# Strict Standards Error while image upload with PHP script

Tags: php, html, image-uploading, image-upload

I try to write an image uploader with php. But it is giving an error when I try.

***Error is:***

**Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xx\xx\xx\profile_image_upload_script.php on line 10**

***Line 10 is:*** `$extension = end(explode(".", $file_name_encrypted));`

---

**image upload script**

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

$file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo "File name:".$file_name;

$file_name_encrypted = $file_name."".md5(rand(1, 1000000));


$extension = end(explode(".", $file_name_encrypted));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152) // 2 MB
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $file_name_encrypted . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024*1024) . " MB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $file_name_encrypted))
      {
      echo $file_name_encrypted . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $file_name_encrypted);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $file_name_encrypted;
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
?>
```

Note: script is getting file name from html form, there is no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note `$file_name_encrypted` will not contain a *real* or *matchable* extension, because your **appending** the filename with md5:

`$file_name_encrypted = $file_name."".md5(rand(1, 1000000));`

e.g `filename.jpg79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4`

So it will never match any in your `$allowedExts` array. Fix that then:

Change that line too:

```
$extension = pathinfo($file_name_encrypted, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Or explode then pass the exploded to the end() function.

```
$temp = explode(".", $file_name_encrypted);
$extension = end($temp);
```

Comment: Also md5 is not encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this is to explode first then use that array in end.
`end()` needs to get its parameter passed by reference because it manipulates internal pointer but if there is no variable reference it will not work correctly.
Try this
`$array = explode(".", $file_name_encrypted);`
then
`$extension = end($array);`

Comment: Now solved strict standards error but there is a new error. `Invalid file
Return Code: 0`

Comment: You are checking extension in a wrong way. O baska bir soru :D

Comment: @hakiko the 0 in that code means upload was OK, but its failing because of what i have mentioned in my answer..